# CIFS mount of volume on synology mounts as 'root'.. and should be 'myaccount'

Tags: permissions, root, smb, synology, cifs

The set-up:
Linux Machine via CIFS -> Synology_Disk_Station @ File_ShareA
"myaccount" is set as the admin account on the Synology

A Ubuntu 18.04 machine at a remote site I've mounted a file share on a Synology with CIFS using the following (edited) line in my /etc/fstab file.

```
//SYNOLOGY/file_shareA/ /home/myaccount/file_shareA cifs credentials=/home/myaccount/.smbcred
```

This mounts great and is fully navigable from the Ubuntu machine... however the permissions are all set to root and this forces me to elevate to sudo to manipulate the files.

the ls -l command in the File_ShareA looks as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root         0 Jun 11 14:27 'Directory One'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 483165473 Jul  7 14:08  zip-file.tar.bz2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root         0 Mar  3 17:08  Directory_2
```

So my question is, How do I mount this volume as "myaccount" and not as "root". To my knowledge the /etc/fstab file requires root permission to work and mount the file share.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching on CIFS settings with the /etc/fstab file. the following line allowed the mount to use my user account

```
//SYNOLOGY/File_Share /home/myaccount/File_Share cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/myaccount/.smbcred,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=mmurray,gid=mmurray,nofail 0 0
```